# Batch rename files in directory with multiple file types

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I need to rename a batch of pngs and I currently have this .sh file

```sh
echo Renaming all files.
echo Please enter a prefix
read prefix
echo Please enter a filetype
read filetype

j=1;
for i in *.{jpg,jpeg,png};
do mv "$i" "$prefix"-"$j"."$filetype";
echo Renaming "$i" to "$prefix"-"$j"."$filetype";
let j++;
done

echo Renaming Complete
```

When I run this it misses the first two files and returns this

```sh
mv: rename *.jpg to on-1.jpg: No such file or directory
Renaming *.jpg to on-1.png
mv: rename *.jpeg to on-2.jpg: No such file or directory
Renaming *.jpeg to on-2.png
```

and then I'm left with files from `on-3.png` - onwards. What's causing that previous error?

Answer (score 2):

Brace expansion happens first in `*.{jpg,jpeg,png}`, i.e. it creates three words: `*.jpg *.jpeg *.png`. There are no `jpg` nor `jpeg` files in the given directory, so the `*` has nothing to expand to, therefore, it remains a literal asterisk. To change the behaviour, you can set the `nullglob` option:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

`*.jpg` will expand to a null string and will not be iterated over in the loop.